# Android: inflater and setContentView could not trigger seekbar event

Tags: android, layout-inflater, setcontentview

I'm using SeekBar for doing some stuff.

The onProgressChanged() would be trigger correctly like below.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main); 
    SeekBar sk=(SeekBar) findViewById (R.id.seekBar1); 

    sk.setProgress(50);
    sk.setOnSeekBarChangeListener
    (
        new OnSeekBarChangeListener()
        {
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser)
            {
                 // Doing something correctly.
            }
        }
    );
}
```

But, if I use LayoutInflater, SeekBar could not trigger onProgressChanged() event, just like below.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();     
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null); 

    setContentView(R.layout.main);      
    SeekBar sk=(SeekBar) layout.findViewById (R.id.seekBar1); 

    sk.setProgress(50);
    sk.setOnSeekBarChangeListener
    (
        new OnSeekBarChangeListener()
        {
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser)
            {
                    // Could not trigger event.
            }
        }
    );
}
```

I'm not sure whether or not using the LayoutInflater in a wrong way, so I try another way to get inflate object.

```
Context mContext = MyActivity.this;  
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Still not work. 
So, my question is why SeekBar could not trigger event if I used LayoutInflater to get SeekBar object.

Comment: change this `setContentView(R.layout.main);` to `setContentView(view);`

Comment: Hi, it still do not work but thanks for your help. :)

Comment: it should work what you did was infalte a layout and you din't set the inflated view to the activity

Comment: It work!!  Just call setContentView(view), thank you Raghunandan!
I must make some mistake at first. Thank you again!